# Elegant and fast way to join all string sequences

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I want to do what title says:

> {"a","b",1,2,3,4,"a",2,2,2,"edg","?"} => {"ab",1,2,3,4,"a",2,2,2,"edg?"}

in the most elegant way. For example one replacement rule for `ReplaceAll`.

I have manage to do this:

```
test = {"a", "a", 1, 2, "A", "b", 123, "a", "end"}
SplitBy[test, Head] /. {x__String} :> StringJoin[{x}] // Flatten
```

> {"aa", 1, 2, "Ab", 123, "aend"}

But I find this way inelegant. Could You help me with creating good pattern?

**Edit**

Bonus request: It should be comparable in duration.

Also there is not need to do this via [pattern-matching](/questions/tagged/pattern-matching).

**Conclusion:**

There are many great answers. Each one is educational and worth an upvote. I should now accept one, the problem is I have not stated this question's goal so clearly, my fault.

- rm -rf's is **the fastes and the shortest** however,
- I decided to **accept** Jacob's answer <strike>as the fastest one and</strike>  because it seems it has not focused attention as it deserves.
- Yves Klett answer fulfill my need of a **single pattern** solution.

As Mr. Wizard pointed out one could think I should accept rm- rf's answer. One could also think Yves Klett should receive it as his answer fits my primordial need.
I will abuse a vague form of this question to give them a bounty insted.

Comment: So I guess procdural stuff would not be to your liking?

Comment: @YvesKlett Let say Pattern matching is not a must. I will restate the question in edit but I will leave first version so Your answer will fit it.

Comment: I just posted an answer using `SplitBy` before noticing that you had mentioned it in the question. Could you explain why you find it inelegant? This really is not a job for `ReplaceAll` (and cannot be done in one call)...

Comment: @rm-rf I don't know. Maybe I do not like the idea that there are many procedures :) SplitBy/ReplaceAll/StringJoin/Flatten. I like doing things in the shortest/fastes way. I know that former does not mean the latter :). Anyway, I wanted to see other's ideas.

Comment: But it is indeed quite clean, IMO (my solution used `StringQ`, which I prefer for clarity of intent, rather than `Head`) and should be fast...

Comment: @rm-rf Without posting this question I couldn't be sure if it is elegant enough. But now it seems it is.

Comment: Why didn't you accept R.M's answer?  It's so much better!  At least on my system `List @@ StringExpression @@ list` is ten times faster than `SplitBy` alone.  Did you try it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard oh, I have missed to test his update :/ that's embarrassing. I have to change conclusion. But I want to reward an effort of Jacob and others. I'm thinking about starting a bounty.

Comment: That's nice of you to award a bounty.  Perhaps you could Accept R.M's answer as you acknowledge that it is **fastest and shortest**, but award the bounty to Jacob as his answer has not gotten **attention as it deserves**? (You are able to change the Accept in case you are unaware.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This is hard decision. His answer is indeed the fastest and the shortest but I sticked with mine as the safer one and not so much slower with problems I'm dealing with. Also I do not want to give Jacob extra reputation but extra attention. :) I still thinking but I will probably stick with that decision.

Comment: Kuba, that's entirely your prerogative.  Please don't think I'm trying to force your hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*R.M's answer below is faster and way shorter than this one*

The main idea of this answer is to avoid testing if elements of the list are strings, but rather to infer which elements are the strings, to get a speed increase. Here is the function

```
joinStringsInList[list_] :=
 Module[
  {splitList = SplitBy[list, StringQ], strs, others, len, bool}, 
  bool = StringQ[First[test]];
  len = Length[splitList];

  {strs, others} =
   If[
    bool,
    {StringJoin /@ splitList[[1 ;; len ;; 2]],
     splitList[[2 ;; len ;; 2]]},
    {StringJoin /@ splitList[[2 ;; len ;; 2]],
     splitList[[1 ;; len ;; 2]]}
    ];
  Flatten[Riffle[strs, others], 1]
  ]
```

Example:

```
test = {"a", "a", {1, 1}, bool, testSplit, 2, "A", "b", 123, "a", 
  "end"}

joinStringsInList[test]
```

> {"aa", {1, 1}, bool, testSplit, 2, "Ab", 123, "aend"}

Comment: You have not misunderstood my dissatisfaction :) Be patient, I will look at Your answer in the moment.

Comment: +1, I had been discouraged by the many lines...

Comment: @Kuba yikes, an accept. I'll have to improve my answer then :P. I'd say the the `StringExpression` solution of rm-rf is best, especially if he makes an error message around it using `FreeQ`. I'm glad you like it, anyway :)

Comment: Do not feel sorry. I've done this :)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I was referring to this: "P.S.: Sorry for pushing the other answers down". :)

Answer (score 23):

Ok, since you dismissed `SplitBy`, which IMO is quite clean, and you wanted other's ideas, here's an unconventional solution that relies on a side-effect of how `StringJoin` works :)

```
list = {"a", "b", 1, 2, 3, 4, "a", 2, 2, 2, "edg", "?"};
List @@ Quiet@StringJoin@list
(* {"ab", 1, 2, 3, 4, "a", 2, 2, 2, "edg?"} *)
```

I wouldn't recommend this for production code. Stick with your `SplitBy` solution (or a faster alternative answer).

A cleaner version using `StringExpression` (thanks to Rojo):

```
List @@ StringExpression @@ list
```

which probably works very similar to Simon's answer because of the `Flat` and `OneIdentity` attribute of `StringExpression`.

Comment: Abuse... I like it! :) `SplitBy` is faster but definitely thanks for that

Comment: Funny...I came up with exactly the same code before seeing yours. You don't need `Apply` for `StringJoin`, by the way. +1.

Comment: Quick... *and* dirty. +1

Comment: You could use `StringExpression` instead of `StringJoin` and avoid `Quiet` and make it faster

Comment: It could work similarly to Simons but it probably has downvalues that match the nonstring arguments, because it is way faster. I guess the `Flat` is probably so that things like `(_~~_)~~(_~~_)` become `_~~_~~_~~_`. However, this means that if your list has a string expression in it, it will split it up and not work properly

Comment: @Rojo `StringExpression` has the advantage of preserving lists e.g. `List @@ StringExpression @@ {"a", "b", 1, 2, {3, 4}, "a", 2}` which to me makes the solution a lot more usable.  Both are beautiful.

Answer (score 14):

I think this satisfies all the requirements, except for elegance and speed:

```
SetAttributes[f, {Flat, OneIdentity}]
f[a_String, b_String] := a <> b

test = {"a", "a", 1, 2, "A", "b", 123, "a", "end"};
List @@ f @@ test

(* {"aa", 1, 2, "Ab", 123, "aend"} *)
```

Comment: Ahh, I was just typing this but I was missing `OneIdentity`. Rojo showed me something similar once. I suppose this is how rm-rfs answer works.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom it looks like rm-rf's but is this one so slow for You too?

Comment: @Kuba This must be very slow. There may be other examples where something like this can be efficient, but if you do not know the implementation details of Flat and OneIdentity, then you have to get very lucky to get an efficient algorithm. To see a little bit what happens, try: `SetAttributes[g, {Flat, OneIdentity}]; g[3] := f[3]; 
g[1, 2] := f[1, 2] g[2, 3] := f[2, 3]; Trace[g[1, 2, 3]] // Column`

Comment: I've been looking at the `Trace` of this, and that is the most bizarre thing I've seen in a while. I learned something, +1. Oh, and I think it meets "elegant"; speed, however ...

Answer (score 7):

<strike>If we are going for least efficient here</strike>, I think I may have a winner (using `Fold`):

```
ffs[any___, a_String, b_String] := Sequence[any, StringJoin[a, b]];
ffs[any___] := Sequence[any];
```

with

```
list = {"a", "b", 1, 2, 3, 4, "a", 2, 2, 2, "edg", "?"};

Rest@{Fold[ffs, 1, list]}
(* {"ab", 1, 2, 3, 4, "a", 2, 2, 2, "edg?"} *)
```

The "1" being auxiliary hence dropped.

**--EDIT--**

Actually amending a little bit makes this quite efficient:

```
 ffs2[any___] := {any}
 ffs2 /: ffs2[{any___, a_String}, b_String] := ffs2[any, StringJoin[a, b]];
```

and

```
Rest@Flatten@Fold[ffs2, 1, list]
(* {"ab", 1, 2, 3, 4, "a", 2, 2, 2, "edg?"}*)
```

and it can deal with longer lists a little better than the one originally proposed by Kuba:

```
longlist = NestList[PadLeft, list, 100000] // Flatten;
AbsoluteTiming[mine = Rest@Flatten@Fold[ffs2, 1, longlist];]
AbsoluteTiming[original = SplitBy[longlist, Head] /. {x__String} :> StringJoin[{x}] //Flatten;]
mine == original

(* {1.370464, Null} *)
(* {1.556161, Null} *)
(* True *)
```

Comment: yes, you're right, I had written this before rm-rf replaced `~~` instead of `<>` (which made it really fast - why do you say it's slow?).

Comment: :) we are splitting hair here. rm-rf's is, like, faster by a factor of 20

Comment: wow, I did not realize that one was so fast. Well, I guess our answers can still be useful because of the remarks on unstability on rm-rfs answer. +1 for you.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I didn't say it was unstable... just that I probably wouldn't use it in production code, because it relied on a side effect and I personally like to write clean code where the _intent_ is clear. The second one, using `StringExpression` seems to be even faster and also the expected (albeit uncommon) behaviour, although I probably wouldn't be able to guess what it's doing from a quick glance.

Comment: @rm-rf sorry if that was a poor choice of words. I guess I was thinking also about the case where a `StringExpression` occurs in the list, as Rojo remarked. I guess that can be tested with `FreeQ` very quickly (I think Mathematica keeps track of all symbols that occur in an expression anyway).

Comment: Funny solution, but much less nice than `FreeQ`: `se = StringExpression;
Module[{StringExpression},
 {
   List @@ (se @@ {"a", "b", StringExpression[thingy, "b"]}),
   StringExpression = se} // First
 ]`. Alright I'll shut up now :P

Comment: Can I ask if is there something important behind that You have used `TagSet` or it is just Your choice?

Comment: @Kuba I don't think it makes any difference the way this is written if you just use `SetDelayed` - I think `TagSet` has been left from when I was playing with the upvalues of my function. I had a left over `//Join` that I spotted and deleted when I edited this... It's a bit sloppily written, but what it does is quite clear :)

Comment: such artifacts happens to me all the time :) (forgot to add earlier: ofc +1)

Answer (score 6):

How about this (bad performance duly noted):

```
test = {"a", "a", 1, 2, "A", "b", 123, "a", "end"};

test //. {a___, b_String, c_String, d___} :> {a, b <> c, d}
```

or

```
test //. {a___, b : Longest[_String ..], c___} :> {a, StringJoin@b, c}
```

> ```
> {"aa", 1, 2, "Ab", 123, "aend"}
> ```

Comment: Thank You. It does fit my needs. +1. I would love to see something without `ReplaceRepeted`. This could be slow sometimes.

Comment: @Kuba yes, it will not be efficient. Your solution will probably perform much better for larger lists.

Comment: I was searching through all the answers just for this one...

Comment: @VF1 are you pulling my leg?

Comment: Haha, no. I just developed an affinity for `ReplaceRepeated` as a terribly inefficient but very elegant solution whenever it's used since I read [Jon McLoone's 10 tips](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/)

Answer (score 2):

A semi-pattern approach...

```
list = {"a","b",1,2,3,4,"a",2,2,2,"edg","?"};
Apply[Join, SplitBy[list, Head] /. {x__String} :> {StringJoin[x]}]
```

> ```
> {ab,1,2,3,4,a,2,2,2,edg?}
> ```

The `StringJoin[x]` is in a list so the `Apply[Join...` will only strip the top-level lists `SplitBy` introduces. This allows elements of list to be `List`s as well.

```
list = {"a", "b", 1, 2, {3}, 4, "a", 2, 2, 2, "edg", "?"};
Apply[Join,SplitBy[list, Head]/.{x__String}:>{StringJoin[x]}]
```

> ```
> {ab,1,2,{3},4,a,2,2,2,edg?}
> ```

`{3}` is still a `List`.

Answer (score -1):

Just for fun, a different way:

```
test={"a","b",1,2,3,4,"a",2,2,2,"edg","x"};
d=StringSplit[FixedPoint[StringReplace[#,RegularExpression["(\\D+),(\\D+)"]:>"$1"<>"$2" ]&,ToString@Row[test,","]],","];
d/.x_String /; StringMatchQ[x, NumberString] :> ToExpression[x]

(* {"ab", 1, 2, 3, 4, "a", 2, 2, 2, "edgx"} *)
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You've now converted everything to a `String`!

Comment: The edit still won't work for, say, `{"a", "b", 1, "1.23"}`