# Built in function without Attributes Listable works as if it has Attributes Listable

Tags: functions, attributes, language-design

Can Built-in function works as if it has `Attributes` `Listable` even if it doesn't have that `Attributes`

Consider this example:

```
Log[a, {b, c, d}]
(* {Log[b]/Log[a], Log[c]/Log[a], Log[d]/Log[a]} *)

ClearAttributes[Log, Listable]
Log[a, {b, c, d}]
(* Log[{b, c, d}]/Log[a] *)
```

Now check `ReplaceAll`

```
Attributes[ReplaceAll]
(*{Protected}*)
x /. {{x -> a}, {x -> b}}
(*{a, b}*)
```

How can `ReplaceAll` behaves as if it is `Listable` although it hasn't this `Attributes`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, they are considered pseudo-listable. Often they are implemented with something similar to

```
f[x_, a_List] := f[x, #]& /@ a
```

Comment: Is this considered a violation of the system and rules that MMA follows. I know it is not necessary (and some times impossible) to make all things follow same rules but this is a kind of disturbing to our organized thinking of MMA. what I am saying here is from positive perspective.

Comment: Why would it be a violation? It is just another rule. What if you want a function to be only partially `Listable`? For instance, if `f`, above, was `Listable`, it would be `Listable` in _both arguments_. As it is, it is only "`Listable`" in the second one. So, attributes can greatly simplify things, but most of the time, what they do can be accomplished from you're own code. There are [exceptions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27756/52), though. Study that one closely.

Comment: Ok I see. that makes sense. thanks

Comment: @Algohi So is this question about not fully listable functions? Or are you looking for a functions that seem to be fully listable without appriopriate attribute?

Comment: @Kuba, I was surprised how does ReplaceAll and some other functions work as Listable functions although they have not this attribute. I thought no function can work one Listable bases unless they are explicitly declared Listable in their Attributes. It appears that they are working in different way.

Comment: `WeierstrassP[]` and `EllipticExp[]` are two examples that come to mind; their second arguments are necessarily lists, so having them only be listable over the first argument is useful.

Answer (score 9):

### ReplaceAll

[`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) does *not* behave as a [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) head.  If it did it would be broken.  Consider:

```
SetAttributes[brokenReplaceAll, Listable]

brokenReplaceAll[{1, 2, 3}, {{2 -> "b"}, {2 -> "X"}}]
```

> Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in brokenReplaceAll[{1,2,3},{{2->b},{2->X}}] cannot be combined. >>

If it *were* `Listable` then arbitrarily nested rule lists would work and they do not:

```
{1, 2, 3} /. {1 -> "a", {2 -> "b", {3 -> "c"}}}
```

> ```
> ReplaceAll::rmix: Elements of {1->a,{2->b,{3->c}}} are a mixture of lists and nonlists. >>
> ```

Instead it simply has particular handling of a list of lists of rules.  This is entirely unrelated to `Listable`.

### Internal listable behavior

There is no reason that a built-in function cannot have `Listable` behavior without that Attribute.  The Attribute is merely a high-level abstraction of the concept.  As [Leonid explains](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35319/121) the fast vector functions implement numeric behavior internally at a lower level:

```
ClearAttributes[Plus, Listable]

Plus[3, Range@7]
```

> ```
> {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
> ```

Note that in the example above the output of `Range` is packed which triggers the low level behavior.

Related:

- [Block attributes of Equal](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3261/121)

Comment: As usual, Leonid get's a +1 from me as I had not seen that answer before. Oh, you can have a +1, too. :)